# PHP ERROR in dropdown menu that hides div's in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I'm trying to link my PHP to my HTML and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I'm doing a dynamic dropdown menu with javascript that hides the different div's. So if I choose the first option it shows a textarea where I can write and search in my SQL database the thing I'm searching. However when I enter the things in the textarea and click send, it just open another tab.
So far this is what I have:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="pesquisar.php" method="post">
<select id="selectMe">
    <option value="option1">Seleccione...</option>
    <option value="option2">Título</option>
    <option value="option3">Autor</option>
    <option value="option4">Editora</option>
</select>


<div id="option2" class="group" style="text-align:center;">Título&nbsp;<textarea name="titulo" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit"; name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
<input type="reset"; name="repor" value="Repor">
</div>
<div id="option3" class="group">Autor&nbsp;<textarea name="autor" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit"; name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
<input type="reset"; name="repor" value="Repor">
</div>
<div id="option4" class="group">Editora&nbsp;<textarea name="nomeEdit" rows="1" cols="40"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit"; name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
<input type="reset"; name="repor" value="Repor">
</form>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$ligacao=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
   if($ligacao == NULL)
   {
               echo "Ligação à BD falhou!\n";
               exit;
    }

    mysqli_select_db($ligacao, "Biblioteca");


        if ($_POST['selectMe'] === 'option2') {
            print("<p>  $titulo </p>");
             $p="select * from Livros where titulo='".$titulo."'";
             $r=mysqli_query($ligacao, $p);
             $n=mysqli_num_rows($r);
             for($i=0; $i< $n; $i++)
                  {
                         $reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);
                         echo "<table>";
                         echo "<tr>";
                         echo "<td>".$reg["idLivro"]."</td>";
                         echo "</tr>";
                         echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>".$reg["titulo"]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                           echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>".$reg["subtitulo"]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                           echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>".$reg["editora"]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                           echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>".$reg["anoPubli"]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                           echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>".$reg["autor"]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                           echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>".$reg["genero"]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                           echo "<tr>";
                          echo "<td>".$reg["stock"]."</td>";
                          echo "</tr>";
                         echo "</table>";

    }
```

PLEAAASE I really need help :l
thanks

Comment: just like you get the value of selectMe from the $_POST, you'll need to do the same for the other ids, e.g. `$_POST['titulo']`.  It might help if you do a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` to see this better.  Your code also only handles if you have selected option2.

Comment: Like @ernie said. Also, if you're new you should learn the Object Oriented style of PHP, and keep your database connection on a separate, secure page.

Comment: If I understand the problem, the problem is that there opens a new page upon sending? Because if that is the problem, just add target="_self" to the form tag.

Comment: You might have an SQL injection by the way 0.0

Comment: My SQL is fine, I tested everything on workbench but when I insert the PHP it just goes wrong. I've done the same thing that I did with option1 for option2 and option3, still doesn't work.